# react-native unrecognized font family FontAwesome5Pro-Solid

Tags: react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I use react-native-vector-icons for icons

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5Pro'
```

All FontAwesome web fonts I put to assets/fonts and add this folder to rnpm section in package.json

```
"rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/Fontawesome/webfonts/"
    ]
}
```

Then I run react-native link

All this fonts I see in info.plist but when

```
<Icon name="user" solid />
```

I see error unrecognized font family FontAwesome5Pro-Solid. It's funny, but on my old macbook all works fine, I just clone my repository and run project and this error appeared...

[image]

What can I to try to solve this?

Comment: I have the same issue since Friday. Works fine on my workstation, but fails for iOS and Android on our build server. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @FrancoisNadeau not yet

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It seems that FontAwesome5Pro-Solid fonts are either [missing](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/964#issuecomment-473394159) are broken in version 6.4.X of [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons).

So, to fix this problem I had to revert back to a previous version in my package.json file:

```
"react-native-vector-icons": "6.3.0",
```

It is important to also remove the ^ in front of the version so that it does not update to the latest version. The maintainer is aware of the [problem](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/964#issuecomment-474146683), and it should be fixed soon.