# react-native-vector-icons Font Awesome 5 Pro icons not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-vector-icons

I'm trying to use fontAwesome5Pro in [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons). Even the fontAwesome5 non-pro icons don't seem to be displaying. The older font awesome 4 icons display. I do have Pro version of fontawesome and I ran the command to automatically update my react-native-vector-icons to pro fontAwesome: `./node_modules/.bin/fa5-upgrade` and entered my fontAwesome npm token. That part seems to have been successful.

I'm getting this error in the app:

[image]

The icons just show up as question marks.

Code:

```
import AwesomeIcon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5Pro'

<AwesomeIcon
     style={{
         marginLeft: 20
     }}
     name={'utensils'}
/>
```

I've put the icons into xCode:

[image]

I've got the Icons in the project as shown in VS Code:

[image]

The `rnpm` in package.json references the fonts:

[image]

I have changed 'react-native-vector-icons` from version 6.6.0 to version 6.3.0 because of [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241303/3935156). But I still get the same error. What else can I check to get these font awesome pro icons working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fonts were not in `info.plist`

Solution: Add this to `info.plist` where the other fonts for the app are located.

```
<string>FontAwesome5_Pro_Solid.ttf</string>
<string>FontAwesome5_Pro_Brands.ttf</string>
<string>FontAwesome5_Pro_Light.ttf</string>
<string>FontAwesome5_Pro_Regular.ttf</string>
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can use ```Solid```or ```Regular```? Only shows light versions.

Comment: I found props. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

After updating the font, run `react-native link` to copy the fonts to the respective platform(ios/android)

Comment: i don't do linking since i assume it was autolinking. your aswer remind me of this might because of autolinking .

Answer (score 1):

in my case, I fixed it by:

1. for ios:

the naming of "FontAwesome5Pro-Solid.ttf" (both add reference to Resources and add to info.plist)

2. for android
   the file naming should be "FontAwesome5_Pro_Solid.ttf" in assets/fonts

the naming is different but the doc never say that.
btw, android must use real device, simulator does not render the fontawesome pro icons.

Comment: Legend... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To use FontAwesome5Pro you should buy a licence.
You can use all free icons of FontAwesome5 by import down text:

```
import FontAwesome5 from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5';
```

Usage:

```
<FontAwesome5 name="youtube" size={60} />
```